# How can I clone a vector of str and create a new list as lowercase in rust?

Tags: vector, rust, clone

I have a question about my code in Rust

I have a Vector of &str and I want to create another but with all values in lowercase.

In javascript, something like this:

```js
const list = ['Por que algo?', 'Por que outra coisa?'];
const newList = list.map(item => item.toLowerCase());
```

I'm trying to make this in rust but I cannot

```rust
    let list: Vec<&str> = vec!["Por que o Freeza matou o Kuririn?", "Por que o Goku ficou nervoso"];
    let list_lower_case: Vec<&str> = list.to_vec().iter().map(|i| i.to_lowercase()).collect();
```

The list_lower_case is converted to `&&str`, but I need just only `&str`

How can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

That is a different error than I got when running it. I think the problem is that the `to_lowercase` method actually allocates a new string with the new case. Because of that, you can't get keep a reference to it because it will be dropped after `map`. It works if you allow the vec to take ownership, by changing `&str` to `String`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let list: Vec<&str> = vec!["Por que o Freeza matou o Kuririn?", "Por que o Goku ficou nervoso"];
    let list_lower_case: Vec<String> = list.iter().map(|i| i.to_lowercase()).collect();
}
```

(I also removed the redundant `to_vec`)